# How to perform an eased scroll using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

I have a `RecyclerView` setup with a horizontal `LinearLayoutManager` that displays views in full page size (i.e. like a `ViewPager` would).

What I would like to achieve is to programmatically smooth scroll to a certain position. However not with a linear scroll like `smoothScrollToPosition(int)` does, but with an ease-in/ease-out effect instead.

I looked at `RecyclerView.SmoothScroller` but from what I could tell there is no way to implement this behaviour, because information about the total scroll distance/duration seems to be missing.

The next thing I tried was to use `scrollTo(int, int)` manually which seems to be unsupported in `RecyclerView`.

I have for now resorted to sending `MotionEvents` to simulate a drag on the recylcer view. But this feels very overkill for what should be a simple problem.

Is there another way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with creating custom RecyclerView and overriding `smoothScrollBy` method:

```java
public class CustomInterpolatorRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

@Override
public void smoothScrollBy(int dx, int dy) {
    super.smoothScrollBy(dx, dy, new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()); //pass your more advanced ease-in/ease-out interpolator here
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.